# how to handle python crawler's urlopen error?

Tags: python, web-crawler, urlopen

When I write python crawler, I often use urlopen. Sometimes it can't open url（So I get an error）, but when I retry to open this url, it succeeds. So I handle this situation by writing my crawler like this:

```
def url_open(url):
'''open the url and return its content'''
req = urllib.request.Request(headers=header, url=url)
while True:
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        break
    except:
        continue
contents = response.read().decode('utf8')
return contents
```

I think this code is ugly... but it works, so is there some elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. You may end up with the same problem, but I found requests easier to work with and also more reliable.

The same request would go like this

```
def url_open(url):
    while True:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
            break
       except:
            continue
return response.text
```

What error are you getting?

Comment: I cant remember exactly what it is, its error code begins with 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going ahead and using the requests API with Sessions and Adapters so that you can explicitly set the number of retries.  It is more code, but it is definitely cleaner:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
http_adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3)
https_adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=3)
session.mount('http://', http_adapter)
session.mount('https://', https_adapter)
response = s.get(url)
if response.status_code != 200 then:
   # Handle the request failure here
   pass
```